Opening Visual Studio projects from Network Drive is very slow
Opening a visual studio project (with visual studio community 2022) takes about 20 times longer than opening a project locally. I know if i ping that computer the latency will be super fast, so what gives? Why is visual studio taking so long to open a project that is stored on a network drive?
Added details : The target network drive is mapped out fully in my local Visual Studio configuration.
